# python pyqt browser, how to disable copy, paste options in that

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, css, pyqt

I'm developing a lockdown browser using Python and PyQt libraries. I need to disable functions like cut, copy, and paste within the browser. I've attempted to inject JavaScript and CSS code, but these solutions are not effectively preventing users from copying and pasting webpage content that are rendered in that pyqt browser

Is there a reliable solution to disable these functions in a PyQt browser?

Comment: You should disable the related actions that can be accessed via [`view.pageAction()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebengineview.html#pageAction), but note that that probably won't completely prevent usage of clipboard actions via keyboard shortcut in editable fields.

Comment: Even if you disable copy-paste, there's nothing to stop the user taking screen-shots of all the pages and then converting them into a pdf. There are plenty of tools available online that can automate this process and generate the output in a few minutes. These tools are simple enough for anyone to use, so if someone wants to copy all your "locked-down" web-page content, they can do it without too much effort.

Answer (score 0):

As you didnt share any code. So I am not sure where you will implement it.
You can create a custom method and try.

```
def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
    event.ignore()
```